# delegate events but exclude certain elements within child div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following code allows me to exclude elements within a nested div,
but how can I change the following to allow for event delegation so I can bind to any added elements.

```
$el.find('.js').not($el.find('div.excluded .js')).on("click", function(e){
                  //code here
});
```

Comment: move the find and not to the delegate selector position converted to a single selector. `.js:not(:has(...))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [:not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.js:not(.excluded .js)', function(){
    //try
})
```